# plot Line and curve intersection point?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i wrote the following matlab code :

```
L=100;
N=[0:L];
D=8.62;
Z=95;
Dmax=1./12;
X=@(N) N./((N.*D)+ Z);
X2=@(N) N./(D+ Z);

z1 = fzero(@(x) X(x)-Dmax, 0);

plot([0 100],[Dmax Dmax],'r')
hold all
fplot(X,[0 L 0 0.3],'g')
fplot(X2,[0 L 0 0.3])
plot(z1, 'ro')
legend('1/Dmax','N/(ND+Z)','N/(D+Z)','N*')
```

i want to plot the point of intersection between the green curve and the red line, the x- value of the intersection and a discontinuous lign connecting the intersection point to x-axis!

Answer (score 0):

To plot it, you have to calculate the intersecting point. I suggest to use the symbolic toolbox, if not available a numerical solution is possible as well.

```
plot(solve(X(sym('a'))==Dmax),Dmax,'o')
```

Comment: @Sam: Do you have the symbolic toolbox? What error do you get?

Comment: @ Daniel R :  plot(solve(X(sym('a'))==Dmax),Dmax,'o') 
??? Error using ==> char
Conversion to char from logical is not possible.

Comment: i'v installed  all the toolboxes proposed by matlab and i always work with syms but i don't know why it's not working !

Comment: @Sam: Which Matlab version do you use?

Comment: @ Daniel R:matlab v 7.12 (R2011a)